# How do I get my express app to refresh data from mongodb server without having to refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm having trouble with getting blog posts to show up on the home page of my express blog app...they get saved (confirmed using mongo shell), but what happens after I click to save a composed post is the app will redirect to an empty home page (except for the default top material). That is, the short version of the post I just composed doesn't appear until I refresh the page manually.

My code:

```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blogDB', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
     
    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'missing blog post title']
      },
     
      content: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'missing blog post content']
      }
    });
     
    const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
     
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      Post.find({}, (err, returnedItems) => {
        if (!err) res.render('home', { homeStartingContent, returnedItems });
      });
    });
     
    app.post('/compose', (req, res) => {
      const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.postTitle,
        content: req.body.postBody
      });
     
      post.save();
     
      res.redirect('/');
    });
     
     
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
     
    <%- include('partials/header'); %>
     
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p><%= homeStartingContent %></p>
     
    <% returnedItems.map(post => { %>
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
    <p>
      <%= `${post.content.substr(0, 100)} ...` %>
      <a href="<%= `/posts/${post.title}` %>">Read More</a>
    </p>
    <% }); %> <%- include('partials/footer'); %>
```

When I console log the array length returned from my database - right after post.save() - the length is zero. So, I'm not sure why this is happening. It could have something to do with asynchronous code, but I wrote another app earlier that used the same type of code seen here without a problem.

Edit: I fixed this with async-await using this syntax:

```
app.post('/compose', async(req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  });

  await post.save();

  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: your hunch is correct, you need to `await post.save();`

Comment: That works perfectly!

Comment: I am not sure if your doubt is cleared or not but according to the question you asked you can make an api request from frontend with `fetch` and then you can display it in your page with simple javascript and by this you don't have to refresh your page.

Comment: For async function always use try and catch block otherwise if something throws an error your app will crash.